# LaTeX ERROR: File `styles/se-wa-input-styles-v0972.tex' not found. (But I have it?!)

Tags: tables, errors

I tried to write a new table but I got this Error. I deleted the table but the error is still there...
The Link: https://de.sharelatex.com/read/rkvpkdzfrcbv

[image: Screenshot sharelatex.com]

Logs:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded > format=pdflatex 2017.7.12)  10 AUG 2018 12:23
>   entering extended mode
>   \write18 enabled.
>   %&-line parsing enabled.
>   **main.tex
>   (/compile/main.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
>   Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
>   (/compile/paths.tex)
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `styles/se-wa-input-styles-v0972.tex' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)
>
> Enter file name: 
>   ! Emergency stop.
>
> l.13 \input{\seWaPathSty/se-wa-input-styles-v0972}
>                                                     ^^M
>   *** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>   17 strings out of 492990
>   285 string characters out of 6132621
>   54148 words of memory out of 5000000
>   3668 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>   3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
>   1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>   9i,0n,6p,88b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>   !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Can anyone please help me?

main:

```
\input{paths}
\newcommand{\seWaSprache}{deutsch}

\input{\seWaPathSty/se-wa-input-styles-v0972}

\input{\seWaPathText/wa-konfiguration}

\input{\seWaPathText/wa-abkuerzungen}

\seIstErsteProjektarbeit{}

\newcommand{\version}{0.972}


\begin{document}

\input{\seWaPathText/00_Title}


\seKurzfassung{}

\seInhaltsverzeichnis[%
einrueckung=ja,
gliederungsebenen=4
]

\seVerzeichnisse[gliederungsebene=section,imInhaltsverzeichnis=ja]{sym}{abb}{abk}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{\seWaPathText/01_Chapter}

\input{\seWaPathText/02_Chapter}

\input{\seWaPathText/03_Chapter}

\input{\seWaPathText/04_Chapter}

\input{\seWaPathText/05_Chapter}

\input{\seWaPathText/06_Chapter}

\input{\seWaPathText/07_Chapter}

\seAppendix{}

\input{\seWaPathText/99_Appendix}

\bibliographystyle{\seWaPathLit/jurabib}

\seBibliography{\seWaPathLit/sources}


\seEhrenwoertlicheErklaerung{} % dieses Kommando sollte standardm\"assig verwendet werden



\end{document}
```

This is se-wa-input-styles-v0972.tex:

> 

```
\documentclass[12pt,BCOR=10mm,headinclude=on,footinclude=off,bibliography=totoc,listof=ignorechapter]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
% 2012-12-13
\ifthenelse{\equal{\seWaSprache}{deutsch}}{% Deutsche Einstellungen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% 
}{% Englische Einstellungen
\usepackage[english]{babel}% 
}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz} % Graphikpaket, das zu pdfLaTeX kompatibel ist
\usepackage{xkeyval} % Definition von Kommandos mit mehreren optionalen Argumenten
\usepackage{listings} % Formatierung von Programmlistings
\usepackage{graphicx} % Einbinden von Graphiken
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/slashbox} % Diagonalen in Tabellenfeldern
\usepackage{framed} % Erzeugung schwarzer Linien am linken Rand zur Hervorhebung von Textteilen
\usepackage{caption} % Korrektes Setzen einer mehrzeiligen float-Unterschrift bei neu definierten float-Umgebungen
\usepackage{floatrow}
% 2012-12-13
\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/bchart} % Kommandos zur Erzeugung von Balkendiagrammen
% 2013-01-27 
\usepackage[boxed,ngerman]{\seWaPathSty/algorithm2e}
%\usepackage[tworuled,vlined,ngerman]{\seWaPathSty/algorithm2e}


% Es wird jeweils die sty-Datei importiert und entsprechende Konfigurationseinstellungen werden vorgenommen

\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-scrpage2} % Formatierung der Kopf- und Fu{\ss}zeilen
\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-footmisc}    % Fussnoten besser formatieren

\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-glossaries-v097} % Abk\"urzungsverzeichnis, Symbolverzeichnis, Glossar

\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-floatrow}    % Definition und Konfiguration von float-Umgebungen (figure, table, die neue programm-Umgebung)
% Achtung: se-jb-varioref muss nach se-jb-floatrow importiert werden; 
% andernfalls ist der counter programm f\"ur die labelformat-Anweisung noch nicht definiert   
\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-varioref-v097}   % Definition von Querverweisen
\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-chngcntr}   % Kapitelweise oder globale Nummerierung von Abbildungen etc.

\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-listen} % Definition neuer, besser formatierter Listen
% 2014-02-02
%\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-kommandos-v097} % neue Kommandos f\"ur Seminar-, Projekt- und Bachelorarbeiten
%\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-kommandos-v0971} % neue Kommandos f\"ur Seminar-, Projekt- und Bachelorarbeiten
% 2016-04-01
\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-kommandos-v0972} % neue Kommandos f\"ur Seminar-, Projekt- und Bachelorarbeiten
% 2012-12-13
\ifthenelse{\equal{\seWaSprache}{englisch}}{\usepackage{\seWaPathSty/se-jb-kommandos-englisch-v0972}}{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The main.tex is not a complete MWE

Comment: Welcome, without a link to this template, we cannot help. Even with a link, only very few people will click it and dig into a horrible template.

Comment: your styles folder seems to be a subfolder of the literature folder. This looks odd.